# RxJava: Pause Code Execution Until Items Are Emitted

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am just starting to learn about RxJava and have been having some struggles with it lately. I have a section of code that needs to be done using RxJava and I don't want the rest of my code to be ran until either `onSuccess()` or `onError()` of my observer are called. My current implementation is as follows:

```
    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse accountAuthenticatorResponse, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) {
        final AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(mContext);
        final String username = account.name;
        String token = manager.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(token)){
            final String password = manager.getPassword(account);
            if (password != null){
                LoginClient client = ClientGenerator.createClient(LoginClient.class);
                String encodedString = encodeClientIDAndSecret();

                // Current implementation of observer
                Single<TokenResponse> single = client.getRxAccessToken(encodedString, LoginClient.GRANT_TYPE, account.name, password, LoginClient.SCOPE);
                single.map(new Function<TokenResponse, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String apply(TokenResponse tokenResponse) throws Exception {
                        return tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
                    }
                })
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String accessToken) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Here is the access token: " + accessToken);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Unsuccessful response...");
                            }
                        });

            }
        }

        token = manager.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(token)){
            final Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, token);
            return result;
        } else {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, accountAuthenticatorResponse);
            intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
            intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, authTokenType);

            final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
            return bundle;
        }
    }
```

Is there any way that I can prevent the rest of my code from running until my observer completes its subscription?

To provide some better context on this, what I'm trying to implement is a custom account authenticator for Android. When the user first logs in, they won't have an auth token, so I obtain a new one using RxJava (as shown above). Then, I need to return a `Bundle` back to the Android `AccountManager`, which depends on whether I was able to successfully obtain the token or not.

I'm able to retrieve the access token using RxJava. However, if I try to read the token outside of the observer, the token is null because the request hasn't yet been completed... That's why I'm hoping to somehow pause the execution of the rest of the code until the subscription is complete.

As always, any assistance on this particular issue would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why don't you simply move that line inside the onSuccess block?

Comment: Because this is nested within another method that has a return type of `Bundle` and `onSuccess()` returns `null`. I'll update my question with the full code snippet.

Comment: @MauroCurbelo I've just updated the question. Appreciate any help on this :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your Single

```
Single<TokenResponse> singleResponse = client.getRxAccessToken(
    encodedString,
    LoginClient.GRANT_TYPE,
    account.name,
    password,
    LoginClient.SCOPE
);
```

then try something like below (The return type of getAuthToken() needs to be changed):

```
@Override
public Single<Bundle> getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse accountAuthenticatorResponse, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) {
    Return singleResponse
        .flatMap(tokenResponse -> createBundle(tokenResponse))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Now create a method `createBundle(TokenResponse tokenResponse)` like this

```
private Single<Bundle> createBundle(TokenResponse tokenResponse) {
    return Single.create(
        e -> {
            String token = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
            manager.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(token)){
                final Bundle result = new Bundle();
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, token);

                e.onSuccess(result);
            } else {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(
                    AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, accountAuthenticatorResponse);
                intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
                intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, authTokenType);
                final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);

                e.onSuccess(bundle);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Now who ever does subscribe on `getAuthToken()` will get `Bundle`

```
getAuthToken()
    .subscribe(
        bundle -> //Use bundle as needed,
        error -> //Handle error scenario
    )
```

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input on this! However, I don't believe I can return anything within `onSuccess()` of the observer. That's because `onSuccess()` has a return type of `void`. Would you agree with this statement? This would also apply to `onError()`.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your requirement. I am sorry for previous answer. I somehow missed the return statement part. Let me know if it works.